# Horizontal Scroll dataTables.js

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

I am having difficulty getting the horizontal scroll to work with *dataTables.js*. The expected result is a table that allows me to scroll horizontally within the table. The current result is a table that extends outside of the container [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements). Is there a solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
     <table id="portal-drivers" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>First Name</th>
                 <th>Last Name</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th>Number</th>
                 <th>Rating</th>
                 <th>Transactions</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>Bugs</td>
                 <td>Bunny</td>
                 <td>bugs@tunesquad.com</td>
                 <td>(310) 530-6789</td>
                 <td>4.8</td>
                 <td>309239045293459823945234895</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#portal-drivers {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#portal-drivers").dataTable({
    "scrollX": true
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change "scrollX" to "sScrollX": '100%'

```
$("#portal-drivers").dataTable( {
    "sScrollX": '100%'
} );
```

Comment: whats the difference between scrollx and sscrollx?

Comment: I also found adding `responsive:false` did the trick for me. I am using ASP Net Zero, which also adds a `dt-responsive` class to the table, which should be removed.

Answer (score 9):

In order to make the datatable scrollable **(header and body both)**, use property `sScrollXInner` along with `sScrollX` as follows:

```
$("#my-demo-datable").dataTable({
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
});
```

Setting **sScrollXInner** to 100% will allow the table to be responsive and show the scroll bar only when the table overflows. At 110%, it will always be overflowing.

Comment: for me changing the "sScrollXInner" to "100" worked for responsive show down.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting this into CSS:

```css
#portal-drivers {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width: 40%;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Really working well. 
I also applied  "sScrollX": '100%'   in datatable application but width issue occur for header.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
    } );
} );
```

To enable x scrolling, you can set the *sScrollX* parameter your container wrapper's width to be. Also the sScrollXInner is used here to force the table to be wider than is strictly needed.

Comment: Re *"you can set the* ***sScrollX*** *parameter your container wrapper's width to be"*: This is partly incomprehensible. Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)? Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74638044/edit) it?

Answer (score -1):

For making datatable scroll-able ,you can try out this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        *"scrollY": 200,
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} )
```